# How to specify JsonFormatter in Web.config for SeriLog?

Tags: serilog

I am trying to figure out how to specify JsonFormatter in web.config for SeriLog, I am also using rolling file sink and that is specified in the web.config as well.

Comment: <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.textFormatter" value="JsonFormatter" /> I will try this since this looks like it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently any support for specifying custom text formatters in XML with Serilog. Using code to perform this configuration, perhaps based on reading an app setting, is your best bet today.

Comment: Ok, thanks Nicholas, I like Serilog a lot so no big deal.

Comment: If it is not possible to define this formatter in config file, can we add this formatter after defining other properties in config file?