# Controlling settings for serilog in app.config

Tags: serilog

I need to log events in Json format using Serilog. I want to use RollingFileSink.
According to the following link, we cannot specify TextFormatter in App.config file. 
[How to specify JsonFormatter in Web.config for SeriLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053859/how-to-specify-jsonformatter-in-web-config-for-serilog)

Is is possible to specify all other configurations like file path in app.config and then add textformatter as JsonFormatter in code while initialing the logger?

Comment: An alternative is to use `JsonRollingFile`: https://github.com/nblumhardt/serilog-sinks-json#rolling-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using plain settings works well for this, e.g.:

```
<add key="filePath" value="C:..." />
```

And:

```
WriteTo.RollingFile(..., ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"])
```